# Java dice rolling game While loops Randomon generation

Tags: java, if-statement, random, printing, while-loop

okay so I am attempting to create a dice game where args[0] is the amount of times the game is played. the game.... two dice are rolled and if the sum does not equal 7 their value is added to a sum. If the sum equals 7 the game is over. I want to keep track of the largest sum out of all the games and the smallest which should be zero always because when the sum equals 7 it sets the sum to 0. 
Here is my code. I don't think what it is printing is what I am going for...help?Also how do i auto format in eclipse?

```
public class diceGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dice1;
        int dice2;
        int count=0;
        int theSum=0;
        int lowest=500;
        int finalSum=0;
        int diceSum=0;
        while (count !=Integer.parseInt(args[0])){
            count=count+1;
            theSum=0;
            while(diceSum!=7){
                diceSum=0;
                dice1=1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1));
                dice2=1 + (int )(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1));
                diceSum=dice1+dice2;
                if (diceSum !=7){
                    theSum=theSum+diceSum;
                if (theSum>finalSum){
                    finalSum=theSum;
                    }
                if (theSum<lowest){
                    lowest=theSum;
                }


                }

                }
            }
        System.out.println("After "+args[0]+" simulations: ");
        System.out.println("Biggest sum: "+finalSum);
        System.out.println("Smallest sum: "+lowest);
    }
    }
```

I fixed it

```
public class diceGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dice1;
        int dice2;
        int count = 0;
        int theSum = 0;
        int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int finalSum = 0;
        int diceSum;
        int totalSum=0;
        while (count < Integer.parseInt(args[0])) {
            count = count + 1;
            diceSum=0;
            theSum=0;
            while (diceSum!=7) {
                diceSum = 0;
                dice1 = 1 + (int) ((Math.random() * (6 - 1)) + 1);
                dice2 = 1 + (int) ((Math.random() * (6 - 1)) + 1);
                diceSum = dice1 + dice2;
                if (diceSum != 7) {
                    theSum = theSum + diceSum;
                }
                //System.out.println("the sum is "+theSum);
            }
            if (theSum > finalSum) {
                finalSum = theSum;
            }
            if (theSum < lowest) {
                lowest = theSum;
            }
            totalSum=totalSum+theSum;
        }
        double average=(double)totalSum/(Double.parseDouble(args[0]));
        System.out.println("After " + args[0] + " simulations: ");
        System.out.println("Biggest sum: " + finalSum);
        System.out.println("Smallest sum: " + lowest);
        System.out.println("The average is: "+average);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is this code doing instead? Auto-format is ctrl+I, which google would have told you faster than we could.

Comment: right-click, source, format. there is a shortcut indicated there, too.

Comment: `theSum=theSum+diceSum;` why do you do that ?

Comment: also, `((6 - 1) + 1)` is 6. I think you parenthesis are misplaced or something. use Random.nextInt(6) + 1 to roll a 6-sided dice.

Comment: You can extract `Integer.parseInt(args[0])` and not calculate it every time.

Comment: can u explain why the lowest sum SHOULD be 0?

Comment: it should not I was wrong

Comment: had to reset diceSum to zero and fix a few small things. posted my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the lowest value of 2 dice when added is 2, not 0.  And if you roll a 7 on the first roll, then you will not update your biggest and lowest.  You need to move those checks outside the loop.

```
        while(diceSum!=7){
            diceSum=0;
            dice1=1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1));
            dice2=1 + (int )(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1));
            diceSum=dice1+dice2;
            if (diceSum !=7) {
                theSum=theSum+diceSum;
            }
        }
        if (theSum>finalSum){
            finalSum=theSum;
        }
        if (theSum<lowest){
            lowest=theSum;
        }
```

Comment: And i needed to reset diceSum because it will always =7 after the while loop

Answer (score 1):

If diceSum is seven, your check for min/max is not executed because you put it into braces of if(diceSum!=7). So if diceSum is seven, the mininum is not updated.
Also the lowest sum is not always 0. For example:

```
First diceroll:
Dice1: Value 5
Dice2: Value 3
```

Which makes a diceSum=8.

```
So it's not equal 7, so theSum becomes 0+8=8
Because 8>0 (theSum>finalSum) finalSum gets updated: finalSum=8;
Because 8<500 (theSum<lowest) lowest gets updated: lowest=8;

Next dice roll
Dice1: Value 4
Dice2: Value 3
diceSum=7
```

Even if you corret your braces like

```
 while (count !=Integer.parseInt(args[0])){
    count=count+1;
    theSum=0;
    while(diceSum!=7){
        diceSum=0;
            //Corrected Random Brace (see comment below your question)
        dice1=1 + (int)((Math.random() * (6 - 1)) + 1);
        dice2=1 + (int)((Math.random() * (6 - 1)) + 1);
        diceSum=dice1+dice2;
        if (diceSum !=7){
                theSum=theSum+diceSum;
        } // CHANGED BRACE POSITION HERE
        if (theSum>finalSum){
            finalSum=theSum;
        }
        if (theSum<lowest){
            lowest=theSum;
        }
    }
}
```

lowest will still be set to 8. Not to zero. The lowest will only be zero, if a game round exist where the dice sum is 7 in the FIRST dice roll.

Comment: Thanks this is helping i'm gettng closer, I have class in ten minutes so I'll see where I messed up.